# Paralellize python prog with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I need to parallelize with the multiprocessing package (which I never used) the following single thread loop

```
    do_something_before_while_loop()

    while anum <= maxnum:


        do_work(anum, a, b,c,d)

        anum = increase_num_by_one(anum)       

    do_something_after_while_loop()
```

(`a,b,c,d` should be the same in all thread calls of `do_work`, but `anum` is thread specific)

I only want to parallelize the while loop so that if using `n` threads one will run one `anum`, the second will run `anum+1`, etc (as long as `anum+n-1<=maxnum`).

How to do it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you try something? What was the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How to do it? I thought it was obvious but I added it explicitly at the end.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No I have never written multithreaded code.